# Date list in text

Tags: python

I have a text document with 32 articles in it and I want to spot each article's date. I have observed that the date comes on the 5th row of each article. So far I have split the text into the 32 articles using:

```
import re 
sections = [] 
current = []
with open("Aberdeen2005.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):
           sections.append("".join(current))
           current = [line]
        else:
           current.append(line)

print(len(sections))
```

I will like to create a list that contains the date for each article, MONTH and YEAR only:[image]

As it can be seen, date comes in the format from the above picture, but sometimes the day is not included, e.g. Thursday.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Andres

Ps. Here is another example of the 16 document:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex underneath the `if` statement you could replace the day:

```
regx = re.compile(ur'(\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4})\s\w{6,9}')
line = re.sub(regx, "\\1", line)
```

**Example:**

https://regex101.com/r/pJ0nZ8/1

**linecache method:**

Using the [**`linecache`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) module you can specifically capture line 5 and write it to a file; if a date includes the weekday it will be truncated. It's possible to do a lot more with this functionality, although I'll leave the finer details up to you.

```
import linecache

w = 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'
l = linecache.getline("Aberdeen2005.txt",5)
m = [d in l for d in w]
c = '2005','2016' # years (optional)

if any(y in l for y in c): # check for years (optional)

    if any(x in l for x in w):
        r = [i for i,v in enumerate(m,0) if v]
        l = l.replace(' '+w[r[0]],'')

    with open("dates.txt", "a") as article_dates:
        article_dates.write(l)

linecache.clearcache()
```

Comment: I am getting an error about the tabs and spaces when I try to insert it. Nevertheless the idea is fantastic, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! It's hard to tell exactly what the line formatting is like from the image, so if you can post the actual first 5 lines from an article into your question that might help. What is the error exactly?

Comment: I just posted the new image. But what about a code that extracts the fith line of each "sections" which in my case is each article and then convert it into a date format?

Comment: The regex search should remove the day of the week if present. There might be a better solution by doing a search of line 5 and then removing the day that way. It's more complicated, although it might be a better approach with what you're asking; if you haven't already resolved the issue I can show you an example.

Comment: By "creating a list" do you mean extracting (eg. December 29, 2005) from the articles and creating a separate list of dates, or do you just want to remove the day of the week from the articles?

Comment: I mean exactly your first point: extracting Month and Year for each article and creating a separate list of dates.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit more clear now... a couple more questions - do you prefer the list as a separate file, dates only, no titles? (eg. `['date1','date2','date3']`)

Comment: In a separate file indeed, only the dates and no title needed :)

Comment: One more question, is each article a separate file?

Comment: each article is in a unique text file called Aberdeen2005.txt, I have already separate each article with the code above "sections", and now is just a matter of recognizing the date of each article and write it on a list. Thanks

Comment: Hopefully the addition to my answer is helpful :)

Comment: You got it mate, lovely answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try the dateutil.parser library. I've found it a bit awkward to work with but it's job is to take strings that look like dates and convert those dates into datetimes. I've found it to be pretty competent.

Documentation is [here](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) and the function you want is parse()  (i.e. dateutil.parser.parse()).